# How to determine the dimensions of several matrices in a text file

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, fortran90, dynamic-arrays

I want to know the dimensions of several matrices, which I read from a file.
I have done the code to calculate the number of rows and total number of elements of the matrix, and know, thus, the number of columns, dividing the total number of elements among the number of rows.

```
program matrix
    implicit none

    integer,dimension(:),allocatable::total
    integer row,io,countRows,columns,m,numElements

    open(12,file='matrix.txt',status='old',iostat=io)
    if (io.ne.0) then
        write(*,*)'error to open file'
        stop
    end if

    !count rows
    countRows=0
    io=0
    do while (io.ge.0)
        read(12,*,iostat=io) row
        if (io.eq.0) countRows=countRows+1
    end do
    rewind(12)

    !total of elements
    io=0
    do m=1,1000
        allocate(total(m))
        read(12,*,iostat=io) total
        deallocate(total)
        rewind(12)
        if (io.ne.0) exit
    end do

    numElements=size(total)-1
    columns=numElements/countRows

    close(12)
end program
```

The problem is that it only works when there is a matrix in the file, because if there are several, separated by one or several blank lines, it tells me the number of total rows and number of total elements of the file.
I need to know how to separate those matrices to count their rows and columns independently.

Sample file would may look like

```
90 21 11 13
12 11 10 11
33 44 76 55

12 12
87 99

33 12 17
45 98 77
```

Comment: Welcome, please take also the Welcome [tour] about this site. I think the problem is just to finish dealing with one matrix and skip to the next one once you find an empty line. You will likely need the line first instead of the list directed reading everything.

Comment: One way to separate the matrices is to also consider the blank lines. Basically, you have to collect the locations of blank lines as they are the end/start of matrices (loc-1 is the end of previous and loc+1) is the start of next matrice and the loc is just some random location of the blank line.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a solution like this, not a fancy one, but seemed to work with the example:

```
program matrix
    implicit none

    integer,dimension(:),allocatable::total
    integer row,io,countRows,columns,m,numElements,icol
    integer mlocs(100,2),imat,countMat,countSpace,nmats
    character(len=256) line
    character linechar

    mlocs=0;
    open(12,file='matrix.txt',status='old',iostat=io)
    if (io.ne.0) then
        write(*,*)'error to open file'
        stop
    end if

    !count rows
    countRows=0
    countMat=1;countSpace=0;

    do while (1.gt.0.0)
        read(12,'(a)',end=100) line
        print*,trim(line)
        countRows=countRows+1;countSpace=1;
        if (len(trim(line)).eq.0) then
            countMat=countMat+1;mlocs(countMat,1)=countRows;
        elseif (len(trim(line)).gt.0) then
            do icol=1,len(trim(line))
                read(line(icol:icol),'(a)') linechar
                if (linechar.eq.' ') then 
                  countSpace=countSpace+1;
                  mlocs(countMat,2)=countSpace
                endif
            enddo
        endif
    end do
100 print*,'Number of lines is ',countRows
    print*,'Number of matrices is ',countMat
    nmats=countMat;

    do imat=1,nmats
       print*,'NUmber of elements in matrix ',imat,' is ',mlocs(imat,2:2)
    enddo

    close(12)
end program
```

Comment: thanks you so much. I used your example to improve mine. Reading the lines as characters, I can differentiate one matrix from another.